# SWIG interface not working for a C++ using a numpy array of long values

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig

I'm trying to call a C++ function from Python passing a numpy array (dtype=int64).
I think that this array should have type `long` in the corresponding C++ function.
In the interface file (SWIG) I declare it as:

```
%apply (long* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(long * connectivity_long, int n_long)};
```

But it gives an error when I try to call my C++ function from Python:

```
core.trial_long(a)
TypeError: trial_long() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The code is given below.
I would really appreciate your help.

```
# test.py
import core
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

print(a)
print(a.dtype)
core.trial_long(a)


// assemble.hpp file    
#include <iostream>

namespace core {

void trial_long(long *connectivity_long, int n_long);

} /* namespace core */


// assemble.cpp file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "assemble.hpp"

namespace core {

void trial_long(long *connectivity_long, int n_long)
{
    std::cout << "Inside trial!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "n = " << n_long << std::endl;
    for (long i=0; i<n_long; i++)
        std::cout << connectivity_long[i] << std::endl;
}
} /* namespace core */
```

and the interface file looks like this

```
%module assemble
%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "assemble.hpp"
%}

%include "numpy.i"
%include "cpointer.i"

%init %{
    import_array();
%}

%apply (long* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(long * connectivity_long, int n_long)};

%include "assemble.hpp"
```

Comment: According to your interface file, your module is named `assemble`, so you should create a `_assemble.so` or `_assemble.pyd` and `import assemble`. I check your example using SWIG 3.0 on *NIX and Windows and it works

Comment: @Jens Munk, I am using namespace "core", so the module _core.so is created. After importing it to the Python test, I get the reported error. I am using SWIG 3.0.12. What exactly version of SWIG are you using?

Comment: It has nothing to do with namespaces. The name in the .i file must match the output name. I am using 3.0.12 as well. Your name is assemble so the pyd file should be _assemble.pyd. Try modifying your .i file to create a module core or vice versa.

Comment: If you havent't found out already, I can post a modified `.i` file with the name `assemble` changed to `core` as well as a `setup.py` which will compile and build your `_core.pyd` or `_core.so` file

Comment: @JensMunk, please do! thank you